# Local notification: repeat functionality not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

Working on an alarm app and trying to repeat alarm weekly using the below code:

```
if repeatWeekly {
    let triggerWeekly = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components([.weekOfYear, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDateTime)
    trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)
} else {
    let triggerDaily = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: currentDateTime)
    trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: false)
}
```

In iOS9 using **UILocalNotification** it is working fine with the following code:

```
let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.weekOfYear
```

But in iOS10 using **UNUserNotification** repeat local notification doesn't work properly, it only repeats for 1 week and never shows up for the next week.

For example, if current date time is "1 Sept 2017" then notification will be repeated for "8 Sept 2017" but not repeated for 15 Sept, 22 Sept or so on.

Thanks

Comment: How did you test the weekly schedule? What about a few minutes repeat, does that work; if so, at what duration does it stop working?

Comment: did you resolve this @NSIceCode?

Comment: Nope, still finding the solution.

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly fine when notification repeated per minute or hours. However, in case of weekly repeated notifications, it only works for the first week after that it didn't come out.